# Can you make a search box using information from a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a search box using data from a table, but I am wondering if it was possible to do the same from a stored procedure. As my assignment says "here is no direct access to the database tables allowed"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return MySQL stored procedure result set using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773890/return-mysql-stored-procedure-result-set-using-php)

Comment: Client sends a query. Client receives the rowset. And only query text investigation allows to define does the rowset is produced by common query or stored procedure.